# No error in REPL, it causes only when I run the app the normal way

Tags: java, scala

I have an app in Scala which uses some library written in Java. In `Build.scala`:

```
lazy val defaultSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ buildSettings ++ Seq(
    scalacOptions ++= Seq("-encoding", "UTF-8", "-optimise", "-deprecation", "-unchecked"),
    javacOptions  ++= Seq("-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation"),
    parallelExecution in Test := false,
    compileOrder := CompileOrder.JavaThenScala   // Java then Scala
  )
```

Here is a simplified version of what I have.

When I run the code below in REPL (`sbt` `"project my-project" "console"` - I have a few modules in my project that's why I use `"project my-project"`) and print "`public class JavaClass1 extends javax.xml.ws.Service....`" then "`val res1 = new JavaClass1() .... res1.getResult()`" it works well, there is no error.

I looked into this more carefully and it turned that the error occurs only when I run an application as a normal application - `"sbt" "project my-project" "run"` :

```
// my app in Scala
object Main extends App {
  val res1 = new JavaClass1() // error
  res1.getResult()
}

// a class in a different library  written in Java
public class JavaClass1 extends javax.xml.ws.Service
{
    private final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JavaClass1.class.getName());

    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            URL baseUrl;
            baseUrl = JavaClass1.class.getResource(".");
            url = new URL(baseUrl, "blabla.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.warning("Failed");
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
        }
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public JavaClass1() {
        super(WSDL_LOCATION, new QName("someDefaultURI", "someName")); // here is the error caused
    }
  //........
}
```

The error is `last test/compile:run`:

```
[info] Running myApp.Main 
[debug] Starting sandboxed run...
[debug] Waiting for threads to exit or System.exit to be called.
[debug]   Classpath:
[debug]   /home/me/projects/test-project/test/target/scala-2.10/classes
[debug]   /home/me/projects/test-project/common/target/scala-2.10/classes
[debug]   /home/me/projects/test-project/project1/target/scala-2.10/classes
[debug]   /home/me/projects/test-project/project2/target/scala-2.10/classes
[debug]   /home/me/projects/test-project/project3/target/scala-2.10/classes
[debug]   /home/me/projects/test-project/./lib/lib123-ws-1.5-javadoc.jar
[debug]   /home/me/projects/test-project/./lib/lib123-ws-1.5-sources.jar
[debug]   /home/me/projects/test-project/./lib/lib123-ws-1.5.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.10.3.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.10/jars/akka-actor_2.10-2.2.1.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.0.2.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.projectlombok/lombok/jars/lombok-0.11.4.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/com.wagnerandade/coollection/jars/coollection-0.2.0.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.javatuples/javatuples/jars/javatuples-1.1.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/net.databinder.dispatch/dispatch-core_2.10/jars/dispatch-core_2.10-0.11.0.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/com.ning/async-http-client/jars/async-http-client-1.7.16.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty/bundles/netty-3.6.3.Final.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.json4s/json4s-native_2.10/jars/json4s-native_2.10-3.2.5.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.json4s/json4s-core_2.10/jars/json4s-core_2.10-3.2.5.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.json4s/json4s-ast_2.10/jars/json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.5.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/com.thoughtworks.paranamer/paranamer/jars/paranamer-2.5.6.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.mockito/mockito-all/jars/mockito-all-1.9.0.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scalap/jars/scalap-2.10.0.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.10.0.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.10.0.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/jars/httpclient-4.2.5.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/jars/httpcore-4.2.4.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.6.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.scalaj/scalaj-http_2.10/jars/scalaj-http_2.10-0.3.10.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/jars/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/jars/jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/jars/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/jars/sbt-idea-1.5.1.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/commons-io/commons-io/jars/commons-io-2.0.1.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/jars/sbteclipse-plugin-2.4.0.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-core/jars/sbteclipse-core-2.4.0.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.scalaz/scalaz-core_2.10/bundles/scalaz-core_2.10-7.0.2.jar
[debug]   /home/me/.ivy2/cache/org.scalaz/scalaz-effect_2.10/bundles/scalaz-effect_2.10-7.0.2.jar
[debug] Waiting for thread run-main to exit
[error] (run-main) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.BindingID
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.BindingID
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseBinding(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at JavaClass1.<init>(JavaClass1.java:46)
  at myApp.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:26)
  at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
  at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
  at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
  at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
  at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
  at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
  at myApp.Main$.main(Main.scala:13)
  at myApp.Main.main(Main.scala)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:72)
  at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:65)
  at sbt.Run.sbt$Run$$execute$1(Run.scala:54)
  at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Run.scala:58)
  at sbt.TrapExit$.sbt$TrapExit$$executeMain$1(TrapExit.scala:33)
  at sbt.TrapExit$$anon$1.run(TrapExit.scala:42)
[debug]   Thread run-main exited.
[debug] Interrupting remaining threads (should be all daemons).
[debug] Sandboxed run complete..
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at sbt.BuildCommon$$anonfun$toError$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1628)
  at sbt.BuildCommon$$anonfun$toError$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1628)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
  at sbt.BuildCommon$class.toError(Defaults.scala:1628)
  at sbt.Defaults$.toError(Defaults.scala:34)
  at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$runTask$1$$anonfun$apply$36$$anonfun$apply$37.apply(Defaults.scala:647)
  at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$runTask$1$$anonfun$apply$36$$anonfun$apply$37.apply(Defaults.scala:645)
  at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
  at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
  at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
  at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
  at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
  at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
  at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (test/compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
```

**UPDATE**:

In REPL:

```
scala> object Main extends App {
     | val res1 = new JavaClass1()
     | }
defined module Main

scala> Main.main(Array[String]())
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Main$.scala$App$_setter_$executionStart_$eq(J)V
  at scala.App$class.$init$(App.scala:42)
  at Main$.<init>(<console>:20)
  at Main$.<clinit>(<console>)
  at .<init>(<console>:22)
  at .<clinit>(<console>)
  at .<init>(<console>:7)
  at .<clinit>(<console>)
  at $print(<console>)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:756)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:801)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:713)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:577)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:584)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:587)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:878)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:833)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:833)
  at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:833)
  at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(ILoop.scala:900)
  at xsbt.ConsoleInterface.run(ConsoleInterface.scala:69)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
  at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.console(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
  at sbt.Console.sbt$Console$$console0$1(Console.scala:23)
  at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Console.scala:24)
  at sbt.TrapExit$.sbt$TrapExit$$executeMain$1(TrapExit.scala:33)
  at sbt.TrapExit$$anon$1.run(TrapExit.scala:42)


scala>
```

**UPDATE2:**

Sometimes it gives other error:

```
[error] (run-main) java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.BindingID.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseBinding(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at JavaClass1.<init>(JavaClass1.java:46)
  at myApp.Main$.main(Main.scala:14)
  at myApp.Main.main(Main.scala)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:72)
  at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:65)
  at sbt.Run.sbt$Run$$execute$1(Run.scala:54)
  at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Run.scala:58)
  at sbt.TrapExit$.sbt$TrapExit$$executeMain$1(TrapExit.scala:33)
  at sbt.TrapExit$$anon$1.run(TrapExit.scala:42)
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings bundle
  at java.util.logging.Logger.setupResourceInfo(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.logging.LogManager$SystemLoggerContext.demandLogger(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandSystemLogger(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.BindingID.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseBinding(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
  at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at JavaClass1.<init>(JavaClass1.java:46)
  at myApp.Main$.main(Main.scala:14)
  at myApp.Main.main(Main.scala)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:72)
  at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:65)
  at sbt.Run.sbt$Run$$execute$1(Run.scala:54)
  at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Run.scala:58)
  at sbt.TrapExit$.sbt$TrapExit$$executeMain$1(TrapExit.scala:33)
  at sbt.TrapExit$$anon$1.run(TrapExit.scala:42)
[debug]   Thread run-main exited.
[debug] Interrupting remaining threads (should be all daemons).
[debug] Sandboxed run complete..
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at sbt.BuildCommon$$anonfun$toError$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1628)
  at sbt.BuildCommon$$anonfun$toError$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1628)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
  at sbt.BuildCommon$class.toError(Defaults.scala:1628)
  at sbt.Defaults$.toError(Defaults.scala:34)
  at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$runTask$1$$anonfun$apply$36$$anonfun$apply$37.apply(Defaults.scala:647)
  at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$runTask$1$$anonfun$apply$36$$anonfun$apply$37.apply(Defaults.scala:645)
  at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
  at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
  at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
  at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
  at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
  at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
  at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (test/compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
```

Comment: Include this at the original question, don't create a new question for this if it's still the same issue.

Comment: What happens if you do `Main.main(Array[String]())` on the REPL console?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, I don't use main in REPL.

Comment: @Alex Well, I'm asking you to do it and report what happens.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, look at my update.

Comment: That error is a bit insane. `App` doesn't have abstract methods, and [line 42](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/App.scala#L42) certainly isn't one. What version of Scala are you using?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, sbt 0.13, scala 2.10.3. But sometimes I see that 2.10 is being used instead for some reason.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, when I replace App with def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { then there is no such the error.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, there is other error occurring sometimes.